# Why would you need both a pullup resistor and a capacitor to ground on an IO pin?

Tags: capacitor, fpga, integrated-circuit, pins, pullup

I was looking at a board schematic and noticed something odd. All the IO pins are identical in function. But for some reason, there is one IO pin that has both a pull up resistor and a capacitor to ground connected to it (while all the others have nothing). Why is this?

(The IO pins come from a CycloneII EP2C5 FPGA if that's relevant info. I've looked at the [pin out documentation](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/dp/cyclone2/ep2c5.pdf) for the chip but there's nothing particularly special about this pin. The FPGA is mounted on a bare bones general purpose development board, and as such has no specific intended function. And all the circuitry on the board is just supporting circuitry like power.)

[image]

Comment: Was it connected to a button?

Comment: No, it's just hanging out on its own

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As this is related to an FPGA, any pin can have pretty much any imaginable function. It depends on the software in the FPGA what the pin will be used for.

In this case the pin is most like used as INPUT, possibly as RESET-pin or similar. *If* the pin was used as an OUTPUT, the output driver would have a hard time charging the capacitor and is easily overloaded, hence OUTPUT config is quite unlikely.

What happens during power on of the circuit, is the pin is pulled low by the uncharged capacitor long enough for the logic circuit programmed in the FPGA to be used as a RESET signal while the power supply stabilizes. I expect the pin logic level to toggle LOW to HIGH after about (order magnitude) 10kΩ × 10µF =~ 100ms after power on.

The only thing that does not make sense to me here is how the cap will discharge when the circuit is powered off. Probably the internal protection diodes of the FPGA are used for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So whoever designed the board wanted to give users the option to use the pin as a RESET pin?

Comment: Possible. Hard to tell without knowing where the circuit originated from. @JetBlue

Comment: The cap will discharge because VCC3.3 will be 0 volt when the board is powered off.

Comment: Updated the question, the circuit is from a bare bones development board. The only circuitry on it is what's needed to power and program the FPGA. So the FPGA has no specific intended use.

Comment: @MartinZabel you probably want a reset upon any power failure, however short it is. Discharge through the resistor is slow and the FPGA state can get corrupted due to low power supply. Usually with a reset circuit you'll have a reverse diode in parallel to the resistor to ensure the cap discharges immediately with the power supply. Anyway, the design probaby relies on the on-chip ESD protection diodes.

Comment: Just revisited a [video](https://youtu.be/CRJUdf5TTQQ?t=4m25s) I had previously watched on hardware debouncing and in it they use the same exact setup (even the values) to debounce a momentary push button. On the dev board there is a similar push button except that it has no circuitry for hardware debouncing (it's connected directly between ground and an IO pin). Maybe the board's designer had initially intended to connect the button to the IO pin the picture... but didn't?

Comment: Possible, but also notice that your push button may wear out more quickly than its spec'd life because of missing current limit when discharging the cap. Wouldn't matter too much if it is infrequently used, but it is poor design practice. Better to have a small (eg. 1k) series resistor to protect the push button from over current.